# hide vs hidden event in dropdown.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am a JS developer studying events and I need some help from you people. I have a very straight forward question. While going through the code of dropdown.js, I came across the following lines of JS :

```
$parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget));

if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return;

$this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
$parent.removeClass('open').trigger('hidden.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget);
```

I noticed how the event 'hide' is triggered before 'hidden'.

**Now**, the bootstrap documentation expalin these events as such:

> hide.bs.dropdown  :: This event is fired immediately when the hide
>   instance method has been called.
>
> hidden.bs.dropdown This event is fired when the dropdown has finished
>   being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to
>   complete).

Notice how the documentation says hidden is fired only after the dropdown is being finished hidden from the user. My question is: is it the placement of code that is causing `hide` to fire first and `hidden` to fire second?

the lines of code can be found [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L104) too.

**EDIT::** :: 
i mean if i were to place `hidden` event before `hide`, would the bootstrap documentation still be right ?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at what is happening in between the first event and the second event, you will see this

```
 $this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
 $parent.removeClass('open') // and then .trigger('hidden.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget);
```

so the two lines mentioned above are responsible for the actual hiding of the element. This means, as long as `hide.bs.dropdown` is placed before those two lines, and `hidden.bs.dropdown` is placed after them , then the documentation will be right

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is **no - the placement/order of the code does not not ensure that hide-hidden are "fired" in that order**. It is entirely possible to delay the execution of all or part of `hide.bs.dropdown()` until *after*  `hidden.bs.dropdown()` has fired.

Browsers have an inner loop called an `event loop` that processes queued events/functions/etc. The "the placement of code" in your example merely shows the order in which those functions/events are added to this queue.

Here's an example of pushing a function to the end of the queue using `setTimeout()`:

```js
// the timeout delay is 0, but it still moves the 'delayEvent' to the end of the queue:
$(document).on("delayEvent", {
  foo: "bar"
}, function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(event.data.foo);
  }, 0);
});


$(document).on("fifoEvent", {
  bim: "baz"
}, function(event) {
  console.log(event.data.bim);
});


$(document).trigger("delayEvent"); // bar
$(document).trigger("fifoEvent"); // baz
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```